# awk to convert to decimal in column unless zero or empty

Tags: awk

The below `awk` executes a produces the output below it, what I cant seem to figure out is how to only apply that formatting in the value in the column isn't `0` or `null`. Since some fields are empty or null zero is used as the value. In my actual data there are multiple columns this is an example of the format.

**file**

```
1E-010
3.40878806010261E-027
0
blank field
```

**awk**

```
awk '{printf "%.10f\n", $1}' file

0.0000000001
0.0000000000
0.0000000000
0.0000000000
```

**desired output**

```
0.0000000001
0.0000000000
0
0
```

Comment: if there is a line `5`, what do you want for it in output? if there is `0.5` what do you want? the value is `5` and `0.5`

Comment: It depends on the value in line 5 (there are several thousands lines) each converted based on the value in them. For example, if it is `0` or `blank` then it is `0` but if it is scientific notation then it is converted. Thank you :).

Comment: check the edit in my comment

Comment: a `5` or `0.5' isn't possible in the data only `0` `blank` or scientific notation is. Thank you very much :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optionally you could do some ternary nonsense with your `printf`:

```
awk '{printf $1~/^0$|^$/?"0\n":"%.10f\n", $1}' file
```

or without the regex:

```
awk '{printf (!NF || $1==0)?"0\n":"%.10f\n", $1}' file


$ cat file
1E-010
3.40878806010261E-027
0

5

$ awk '{printf $1~/^0$|^$/?"0\n":"%.10f\n", $1}' file
0.0000000001
0.0000000000
0
0
5.0000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '$1!=0 && NF{printf "%.10f\n", $1;next} 1'  Input_file
```

After running code following will be output.

```
cat Input_file
1E-010
3.40878806010261E-027
0
blank line here.....
awk '$1!=0 && NF{printf "%.10f\n", $1;next} 1'  file886274524264
0.0000000001
0.0000000000
0
blank..... here..
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{printf (0+$1 > 0 ? "%.8f" : "%d")"\n", $1}' file
```

The "0+$1" is the trick, to convert string values to numbers (including the empty string).